# Generate Script with UPDATE if exists else INSERT (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, auto-generate

I want to create "UPDATE if exists else INSERT" statements for existing values in a table with the following pattern:

```
    if exists (select 1 from TABLE_NAME where Ident_Column=Identifier ) 
    update TABLE_NAME set   
        Column1=Value1,
        Column2=Value2,
        Column3=Value3,
        ...
         where Ident_Column=Identifier
    else
        insert into TABLE_NAME ( Column1, Column2, Column3, ...)
        select Value1, Value2, Value3, ...
    go
```

I try to use the MSSQL Mangement Studio (2014) script generator, but I do not get the output as desired.

EDIT: The desired output IS the SQL statement, @Rusland K. &  Nick.McDermaid . I want to use the script generator to generate this SQL code for each (or selected) rows of the table TABLE.
Identifier is not a variable, its a value.
If the value Identifier in Column Ident_Column exists, set the row accordingly (Value 1-n). If that Identifier is not found in any row, create a now row accordingly.
@bmsqldev: This is the entire code (just replaced the real column/table names and the concrete values)

Actually I'm don't understand what caused the missunderstanding here. If you can tell, I'd be happy to learn.

EDIT2: I endet up writing a small script which converts the script output of MSSQL Mangement Studio according to this pattern, which took me about 2 hours.

Comment: use merge to do your requirement

Comment: No need to. You can do this using `MERGE`. Or simply remove the `IF` and use the proper `WHERE` statements in the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` clauses. The speed will be the same as MERGE. You could also join the target table with either a source query or TVP to perform the MERGE/UPSERT for all rows at once

Comment: And what otput is desired?
p.s. Merge is too buggy...

Comment: @RuslanK. MERGE is not buggy although it requires as much coding as the two separate statements. No result is asked so what should it matter? All statements have `OUTPUT` clauses though

Comment: you should show the entire code of yours. seems you have some issue with where clause,

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @RuslanK. you'll find some of these issues have been fixed but the entry in Microsoft Connect hasn't changed. In any case, writing two separate UPDATE/INSERT statements will work and take the same amount of code.

Comment: Please expand on "I do not get the output as desired." - your query looks mostly fine to me although I assume Identifier is a variable?. Don't complicate things with `Merge`

Comment: Updated Post according to your questions

Comment: Oh so you want to write a script that generates a script? So really the deliverable here is a script that produces many repeated versions of your above script? In this case I recommend you first generate your input dataset in a 'table value constructor' format as per here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx then input that into a `merge` statement. Then your data and merge logic are in seperate parts.

Comment: I intended to use the script generator to create those statements, but I did not find out how this is possible (if at all).
I didn't want to write a script, I just wanted to use the script generator - but I had to write a standalone-tool to convert the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE TABLE_NAME AS TARGET
    USING(
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
        DBO.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE
       IDENT_COLUMN=IDENTIFIER 

) AS SOURCE
    ON(
    TARGET.COLUMN1 = SOURCE.COLUMN1
    AND TARGET.COLUMN2 = SOURCE.COLUMN2
    AND TARGET.COLUMN3 = SOURCE.COLUMN3

)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET
        TARGET.COLUMN1=SOURCE.VALUE1,
        TARGET.COLUMN2=SOURCE.VALUE2,
        TARGET.COLUMN3=SOURCE.VALUE3,
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        (
            COLUMN1, COLUMN1, COLUMN1, ...)

    VALUES(
        (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, ...
        ),
        SOURCE.VALUE1,
        SOURCE.VALUE2,
        SOURCE.VALUE3,...
    );;
```